# How do I change "iOS Default" build settings?

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode

Looking at the hierarchy of build settings for a project, the highest level is titled "iOS default." **Can anyone tell me how I can alter these default values?**

**Please note:** I am **not** looking to create another build target and I am **not** looking for advice on how to create a .xcconfig file. I am looking to override the "iOS default" values for a specific reason. (That reason is due to what I consider a major Xcode bug. In short, a 64-bit sub-project embedded in a 32-bit main-project never checks with the main project's supported architectures when determining its "active architecture." So in debug mode with "build active architecture only" enabled, debugging a 32-bit project on a 64-bit device causes the sub-project to build a 64-bit binary and the main-project to build a 32-bit binary. The issue is not existent in a release build with "build active architecture only" disabled and can be corrected in a debug build by disabling that same setting, but I hate to dip into my vendor libraries, so I'd rather override this setting from above.)

Thanks in advance.